# ClassNotFoundException: org.asynchttpclient.defaultasyncHttpClientConfigBuilder error

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Recently I have upgraded my selenium version from 3.141.59 to 4.1.0 and whenever I am running my script getting the below error

Console &3
N. Results of running class TestRunner
髪

```
minated> TestRunner [TestNG] C:\Program FilesVava\jdk1.8.0_321\bin\javaw.exe (Nov 18, 2022, 6:46:33 PM)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/asynchttpclient/DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.createHttpClient(NettyClient.java:91 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty .NettyClient.<clinit>(NettyClient.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.jav at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient$Factory.createClient(TracedHttpCli at org-openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor-<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:107) at org.openqa.selenium. remote. RemoteWebDriver.createTracedExecutorWithTracedHttpClient(Re at org.openqa.selenium. remote. RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java: 146) at com.cucumber.utility.BrowserFactory.launchBrowser (BrowserFactory. java: 82) at com.cucumber.step.StepDefinition _.launch_the_browser_and_navigate_to_ at ?.Launch the browser "yes" "Chrome" "105.0" "Windows 10" and navigate to URL Env "h sed by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig$Bui
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader. java: 387)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc. Launcher$ApplassLoader. loadClass (Launcher. java:355) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader. java: 351)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.createHttpClient(NettyClient.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.<clinit>(NettyClient.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing. TracedHttpClient$Factory.createClient (TracedHttplie at org.openqa.selenium. remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor. java:107) at org.openga.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.createTracedExecutorWithTracedHttpClient(Rem at org.openqa.selenium.remote. RemoteWebDriver.<init> (RemoteWebDriver.java:146) at com.cucumber.utility.BrowserFactory.launchBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:82) at com.cucumber.step.StepDefinition_.launch_the_browser_and_navigate_to_Paypal at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke® (Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImp1.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImp1.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method. java: 498) at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils. java: 26)
=+
Timenit timenit / Timennt
```

I had okhttp3 class where now I have commented it due to its throwing error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi My issue got resolved by adding asynchttpclient maven dependency in POM.